# TypeOrm:RepositoryNotFoundError in NestJS while seeding

Tags: webpack, nestjs, typeorm, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I am trying to seed my database using NestJS and TypeORM.

I have a migration file that creates an `exercise` table, and a seeding file that inserts an `ExerciseEntity` into the table. The main difference between these files is that the migration file runs queries directly:

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
  await queryRunner.query(
    `CREATE TABLE ...`
  );
}
```

while the seeding file gets the repository:

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
  await queryRunner.manager.getRepository<ExerciseEntity>(ExerciseEntity).save(
    someExerciseEntity
  );
}
```

This `getRepository` is the one creating the error.

```
RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "ExerciseEntity" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
    at new RepositoryNotFoundError (C:\Users\Dev\Documents\team-management\src\error\RepositoryNotFoundError.ts:10:9)
    at EntityManager.getRepository (C:\Users\Dev\Documents\team-management\src\entity-manager\EntityManager.ts:1194:19)
    at SeedExercises1584903747780.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\Documents\team-management\dist\apps\api\_seeds\dev\webpack:\_seeds\dev\1584903747780-SeedExercises.ts:7:31)
```

In a service I get the repository and save entities without an issue. The problem only happens while seeding.

I register TypeORM as follows:

```
// app.module.ts
@Module({})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  static forRoot(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: AppModule,
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          envFilePath: '.env.dev',
          validationSchema: validationSchema()
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          imports: [ConfigModule],
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => databaseProviders(configService)
        }),
        ExercisesModule.forRoot()
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

where:

```
// database.provider.ts
export const databaseProviders = (configService: ConfigService) => {
  const normalizePath = (_path: string) => (path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, _path)));

  const commonDB: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'sqlite',
    entities: [...exercisesEntities]
  };
  // exerciseEntities comes from an index.ts in an exercise library
  // import { ExerciseEntity } from './exercise.entity';
  // export const exercisesEntities = [ExerciseEntity];

  const defaultDB: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    ...commonDB,
    database: path.join(
      configService.get('APP_ROOT_PATH', '.'),
      configService.get('TYPEORM_DATABASE', 'gym-dev.sqlite')
    ),
    logging: configService.get<boolean>('TYPEORM_ENABLE_LOGGING', true) ? ['query', 'error'] : [],
    cache: true,
    synchronize: configService.get<boolean>('TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE', false),
    migrations: [normalizePath('_migrations/*.js'), normalizePath('_seeds/dev/*.js')],
    migrationsRun: configService.get<boolean>('TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN', true),
    dropSchema: configService.get<boolean>('DROP_SCHEMA', false)
  };

  return defaultDB;
};
```

I am using `nrwl/nx` for compiling and serving the application using the following webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = function(config, context) {
  const baseDirectory = path.resolve(config.output.path);

  const entityPaths = ['libs/feature/api/**/entities/*.js'];
  const migrationPaths = ['_migrations/*.js', '_seeds/**/*.js'];
  config.entry = {
    ...config.entry,
    ...getEntityEntries(entityPaths),
    ...getMigrationEntries(migrationPaths)
  };
  // getEntries functions allows the compilation of entities and migrations

  // Output
  config.output = {
    path: baseDirectory,
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  };

  return config;
};
```

My `dist` structure ends up being:

```
dist
|-apps
  |-api
    |-_migrations  // contains compiled migrations
    |-_seeds       // contains compiled seeders
    |-lib
      |-entities   // contains compiled entities
    |-main.js
```

As seen in `app.module.ts` I am using `TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync` to be able to inject the config service. I am suspecting that maybe when the seeders are executed the repositories are not yet registered. That would explain that later, while running the web application, the service can access the repository.

Any idea how can I solve this?
Is my configuration wrong or missing something? Is there a way in the seeder to wait for the repositories to be registered, if that's the problem?

EDIT:
It doesn't have anything to do with `TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync`. I did the following changes:

```
// app.module.ts
@Module({})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  static forRoot(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: AppModule,
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          envFilePath: '.env.dev',
          validationSchema: validationSchema()
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(databaseProvidersSync()),
        ExercisesModule.forRoot()
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

```
// database.providers.ts
export const databaseProvidersSync = () => {
  const normalizePath = (_path: string) => (path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, _path)));
  const defaultDB: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'sqlite',
    entities: [...exercisesEntities],
    database: path.normalize(`C:\\Users\\Dev\\Documents\\team-management\\gym-dev.sqlite`),
    logging: ['query', 'error'],
    cache: true,
    synchronize: false,
    migrations: [normalizePath('_migrations/*.js'), normalizePath('_seeds/dev/*.js')],
    migrationsRun: true,
    dropSchema: true
  }

  return defaultDB;
}
```

And the error is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the current TypeORM version (0.2.24).

I switched to 0.2.22 and it worked, without changing anything else.

Here is the issue I opened with this text, and at the end asking when do they expect it to be fixed:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5781
And here some issue that seems to talk about this problem in the last version:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5676

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the issue for me as well. I have wasted a few hours banging my head at this, it seems as of 0.2.34 the issue hasn't been fixed yet.